# 3 Tables Relation In Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a little problem,

i can't see how can i make a three table relation on Laravel.

**DELETED**

If someone can help me, I take notes !

Thanks !

Comment: > One Contact have one Job in Many Films ... is not clear , show your relations between tables using the 3 standards ; 1-1 , 1-n or n-n

Comment: Looks better, but still not enough to understand (and not guess) your relations,

Comment: Before coding, it's very important to be able to clarify your relations as I wrote before, (er)read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships then evrything should be only method.

Comment: Yes I see, but I don't want to make the relations for you, if not you'll not understand. Begin by 2 tables if you want.

Comment: Last time for me : a relation is : ono-to-one or one-to-many or many-to-many between 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you need to create a relationship to your pivot table and then, you can create relationships to both table.

```php
class Contact extends Model
{
    public function filmJobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ContactFilm::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class ContactFilm extends Model
{
    public function film()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Film::class);
    }

    public function job()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Job::class);
    }
}
```

You can now use it like that: `$contact->filmJobs[0]->film` and `$contact->filmJobs[0]->job`.